An optimal and simple solution for a filled node on a pattern in TiKZ
What could be a better way to achieve a nicer pattern and have a white rectangle in node
X on top of the pattern in the foreground?

Here there is a MWE of the drawing.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node [circle, draw, thick, inner sep=9pt] (X) {$X$} 
(2,0) node [circle, draw, thick, inner sep=7pt] (Y) {$Y$};
\fill[pattern=north east lines](0,0) circle(0.65);
\draw [thick, ->] (X) .. controls +(45:1cm) and +(135:1cm) .. node [above] {$f$} (Y);
\draw [thick, ->] (Y) .. controls +(-135:1cm) and +(-45:1cm) .. node [below] {$g$} (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


I don't know if it's the best way, but you could draw two times the X node, with two fillings:
\path[fill]
  (0,0)
  node [circle, draw, thick, inner sep=9pt, pattern=north east lines] (X) {\phantom{$X$}}
  node[fill=white, inner sep=2pt]{$X$}

Example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill]
    (0,0)
    node [circle, draw, thick, inner sep=9pt, pattern=north east lines] (X) {\phantom{$X$}}
    node[fill=white, inner sep=2pt]{$X$}
    (2,0)
    node [circle, draw, thick, inner sep=7pt] (Y) {$Y$};

    \draw [thick, ->] (X) .. controls +(45:1cm) and +(135:1cm) .. node [above] {$f$} (Y);
    \draw [thick, ->] (Y) .. controls +(-135:1cm) and +(-45:1cm) .. node [below] {$g$} (X);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your kindness. I truly appreciate it. +1

@jilab, you can avoid the double-stroked X by using {\phantom{$X$}} in the first node.

@Rmano You right, it's better. I edited the answer.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, thick, inner sep=13pt, pattern=north east lines, label={[fill=white, inner sep=1.5pt]center:$X$}] (X) {};
\node[circle, draw, thick, inner sep=7pt] (Y) at (2,0) {$Y$};
\draw[thick, ->] (X) to[bend left=45] node[above] {$f$} (Y);
\draw[thick, ->] (Y) to[bend left=45] node[below] {$g$} (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


